# Apostrophe issue in url with OData

Tags: odata, apostrophe

I am using `oData protocol` which add the filter criteria in the url

E.g. `/api/restaurants/getall?$filter=substringof('macdonald',Name)`

My problem when the value has apostrophe like (`macdonald's`) it will break the url

It works fine if I replace it with `%26` like `macdonald%26` but by adding `s` (`macdonald%26s`) the url will not work

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

When inside the quoted string a single quote can be escaped by doubling it. So in your case it would look like 'macdonald''s'.

Comment: Thanks, now it escape the single quote problem but it didn't retrieve the selected name. maybe the OData didn't receive it correctly

Comment: From this I can't tell what's wrong. If you can debug the service you might be able to intercept the query (depends on the query provider you're using) to see what it's looking for. Or maybe some kind of SQL profiler would tell you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post, but I'll point out that the arguments in the substringof expression are switched.

https://help.nintex.com/en-us/insight/OData/HE_CON_ODATAQueryCheatSheet.htm

This is aside from the apostrophe (single quote) problem.