# Issue with apostrophe in OData request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, odata

I have a text input which I'm using to pass a value through JS, to get filtered data of names from a JSON file using [OData](http://www.odata.org/documentation/) query parameters.

If someone has an apostrophe in their name, I get a bad request when I pass the URL.

I understand that apostrophes should be [escaped by double quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517529/apostrophe-issue-in-url-with-odata). I've tried this, and while the request doesn't break, it gets passed with two apostrophes which doesn't match the data (resulting in no results).

Here's a high level of what my code looks like:

**JSON**

```
{
    "value": [{
        "Title": "John O'Smith"
    }]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="John O'Smith" />
<button>Search</button>
```

**JS**

```
var term = $('input').val();
var searchTerm = term.replace(/'/g, "''");

var serviceURL = "/api/service?&$filter=contains(Title,'" + searchTerm + "')";

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $.get( serviceURL, function( data ) {
        // Code to display filtered JSON data
    });
});
```

When I pass the `serviceURL` above via AJAX, the URL will appear as:

```
/api/service?&$filter=contains(Title,'John O''Smith')
```

The request works, but it comes through with two apostrophes which doesn't match my JSON object.

If I pass it as is - without the replace - I get a `Bad Request`.

I've tried escaping it through other traditional methods as well ('\'', encodeUriComponent)

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to address this?

## Update

Unfortunately it appears there was a separate issue or it was heavily cached, as everything above is now working as expected.

Comment: Its will be hard to answer without knowing the format of the API parameters

Comment: @Musa I'd be happy to provide whatever info I might be missing. The request follows standard OData parameters http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html

Comment: Have you tried swapping the single quotes with the double quotes? So instead your service URL would be:
'/api/service?&$filter=contains(Title,"' + searchTerm + '")'

Answer (score 5):

You have a space in the name so you'll need to encode it after doubling the apostrophes:

```
var term = "John O'Smith";
var searchTerm = encodeURIComponent(term.replace(/'/g, "''"));

var serviceURL = "/api/service?&$filter=contains(Title,'" + searchTerm + "')";
```

Which will produce:

```
/api/service?&$filter=contains(Title,'John%20O''Smith')
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect how the URL is truly passed. When I send it, the url does go through with %20 and %27 in place of special characters - I just wrote it that way for easier viewing. Regardless the space does not throw the error, the error only happens when there is a single quote.

Comment: It shouldn't use %27 it should remain as two single quotes, like in my output example.

Comment: With further thought I'm not sure if you need to escape the space - I expect you probably don't in this case - but your `%27John%20O%27%27Smith%27` is definitely wrong - it should be actual apostrophes rather than %27

Comment: Thanks @K Scandrett - I went through this pretty heavily on postman today, and ran a number of options swapping apostrophes for %27. Unfortunately no matter what combination I use it still throws the same result

Comment: Alright, so I must have been passing something else incorrectly because now - it works every time regardless of encoding! I must be losing my mind here. It looks like double apostrophe does appropriately escape characters.. so I have no idea what was causing it to break earlier. I'll reward you the bounty for sticking with me here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping each single quote with a double quote and vice versa.

Alternatively you could just chain together javascripts concat() method for strings. Docs here: [concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried the double quote approach and that also throws a bad request, I'll attempt it again to double check to make sure that's the case.

Separating the strings and combining is my backup plan though!